# Mirroring armature bones

Tags: modeling, armature, bones

So recently I started making blender models for smash bros mods, right now I am facing an issue with one of the models and is that I want it to be symmetric so I took the right arm, flipped it and put it where the left should be, however I am now seeing that the bones on the left arm are still attached to the right arm, is it possible for me to make the bones of the left arm work on the flipped right arm I made?

Answer (score 0):

Go to vertex groups properties, search for all vertex groups that have something like a .L or _left suffix, and rename it as .R or _right.

The renaming operation has to be performed with the mesh unparented (Alt P) and without any armature modifier, for preventing any change to the names of the bones.

At the end you can re-parent the mesh to the armature using Ctrl P > "Armature deform" option.

Answer (score 0):

You could mirror your arm with the *Mesh > Symmetrize* operation (don't forget to merge the vertices by distance so that the new arm sticks to the shoulder):

[image]

Select all the vertices of the new arm and remove from all groups:

[image]

Select an existing vertex group (let's say *arm1_R*) and duplicate:

[image]

Then mirror the new group and rename it (*arm1_L*):

[image]